# perl suppressing warnings when executing java class

Tags: perl

I have a java code  at server side which calls perl at client side  and perl calls a java class for validationin client side.In server side I expect output like this which is constructed at my client side java class The below tag is constructed in client java class at server java i check this tag and say my execution was success and make some decisionins

```
<Composites>
    i=0
    compositedetail=swlib:soaprov/soacomposite=eis/FileAdapter#eis/FileAdapter#
    swlib:soaprov/soacomposite=eis/FileAdapter#eis/FileAdapter# starts with swlib
    </Composites>
```

I Execute perl which contains below lines

```
my $keyStoreLoc = $emState.'Test.jks';
my $secOptions="-Dweblogic.security.SSL.trustedCAKeyStore=$keyStoreLoc";  
my $className = 'xyz.AdapterValidator';
my $command = $java . ' -classpath ' . $classpath . ' ' . $secOptions
      . ' ' . $className . ' ' . $serviceUrl . ' ' . $composites;
```

Now the isssue in SSL it generate some warning messages and gives output like below

```
<May 7, 2013 1:21:59 AM IST> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090905> <Disabling CryptoJ JCE Provider self-integrity check for better startup performance. To enable this check, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultJCEVerification=true> 
<May 7, 2013 1:21:59 AM IST> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090906> <Changing the default Random Number Generator in RSA CryptoJ from ECDRBG to FIPS186PRNG. To disable this change, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultPRNG=true> 
<May 7, 2013 1:21:59 AM IST> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=CertGenCA,OU=FOR TESTING ONLY,O=MyOrganization,L=MyTown,ST=MyState,C=ka". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<Composites>
i=0
compositedetail=swlib:soaprov/soacomposite=eis/FileAdapter#eis/FileAdapter#
swlib:soaprov/soacomposite=eis/FileAdapter#eis/FileAdapter# starts with swlib
</Composites>
```

Is there a way to do supress them in perl?I need only my tag not warnings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just filter out the output. If you put the output to the `$output` variable, the following code will remove warnings:

```
for (split /^/, $output) {
    if ($_ =~ /<Security>/) {
        next;
    }
    print "$_"; # print line without a warning.
}
```

Comment: This warnings are coming from java file when i call a java file from perl I am just calling my $command = $java . ' -classpath ' . $classpath . ' ' . $secOptions . ' ' . $className . ' ' . $serviceUrl . ' ' . $composites;