# calling a java class from perl without using system

Tags: perl

I have a java code at server side which calls perl at client side and perl calls a java class for validation client side.In server side I expect output message of string type  constructed at my client side java class .For calling java class in my perl I am calling like below

```
 my $command = $java . ' -classpath ' . $classpath . ' ' . $secOptions . ' ' . $className . ' ' . $serviceUrl . ' ' . $composites;
print `$command`;
```

Can perl call java without System command?The issue is some messages are getting printed which are printed in java class I want to assign output from java class and parse it and send back to my server side

Comment: possible duplicate of [perl suppressing warnings when executing java class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406805/perl-suppressing-warnings-when-executing-java-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to tell from your question exactly what you want to do but this might do the trick

```
open(my $program, "$command|") or die "$command $!";  #open program on a pipe
my @results=();
while(<$program>) {
  push @results,$_;  # store output
}
```

For other options see perldoc perlipc http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html